# Vue.js/Vuetify: How can I make the v-card-actions reactive?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have 4 cards (3 in the first row, 1 in second). Every time I resize my browser window my `v-card-actions` contents do not react. In pictures, this is when everything is ok:

[image: before]

And this is when I resize my browser window:

[image: after]

And finally here's my code:

`.vue`

```
<v-container
        grid-list-lg
    >
        <v-layout
            row
            wrap
        >
            <v-flex
                v-for="teacher in teachers"
                :key="teacher.firstName"
                md-4
                xs4
            >
                <v-card
                    flat
                    tile
                >
                    <v-img
                    :src='teacher.src'"
                    height="260px"
                    ></v-img>

                    <v-card-title
                        primary-title
                        class='blue--text'
                    >
                        Dr. {{teacher.firstName}} {{teacher.lastName}}, {{teacher.specialty}}
                    </v-card-title>

                    <v-card-text class='body-1'>
                         M.S at {{teacher.ms}} <br>
                         M.S.C at {{teacher.msc}}
                    </v-card-text>

                    <v-card-actions>

                        <v-btn
                            flat
                            small
                            color='indigo darken-4'
                        >
                            More
                        </v-btn>

                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>

                        <v-btn
                            flat
                            small
                            color='indigo darken-4'
                        >
                            Schedule an Appointment
                        </v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
```

`<script>`

```
data() {
    return {
      teachers:[
        {firstName:'Jon', lastName:'Doe', specialty:'PE', ms:' University of Georgia',
         msc:'University of Georgia', src:'https://source.unsplash.com/kmuch3JGPUM'},
        {firstName:'Maria', lastName:'Doe', specialty:'Philology', ms:'University of Atlanta',
         msc:'University of Atlanta ', src:'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/3.jpg'},
        {firstName:'Jon', lastName:'Jon', specialty:'Mathematics', ms:'University of Michigan',
         msc:'University of Michigan', src:'https://source.unsplash.com/Jy4ELSGPHTc'},
        {firstName:'Peter', lastName:'Xavier', specialty:'Mathematics',
         ms:'University of Miami', msc:'University of Miami',
         src:'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/71.jpg'},
        {firstName:'Peter', lastName:'Miros', specialty:'Mathematics', ms:'University of Miami',
         msc:'Georgetown University', src:'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/20.jpg'},
        }
      ]
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<v-card-actions>` element does react to browser width changes.
What you are seeing is an issue with the Vuetify `<v-button>` element as it does not (by default) wrap text to fit.

You have a few options:

1. Add custom CSS for your buttons to accommodate - tricky and a bit too much hacking for my liking.
2. Make your own button element just for this - seems overkill, but I've done this when I also want a button to stand out or look different enough to Vuetify's standard.
3. Modify your button text to be shorter - Try one word like "Booking" or "Appointments", and even modify the text (or change to an icon) depending on screen size if you want to get fancy.

Personally, I'd recommend option 3.

---

**EDIT: Added `xs12 sm6 md4` sizing and some minor formatting changes to highlight different elements**

```
 <v-container grid-list-lg>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex v-for="teacher in teachers" :key="teacher.firstName" xs12 sm6 md4>
          <v-card>
            <v-img :src="teacher.src" height="260px "></v-img>

            <v-card-title primary-title class='blue--text'>
              Dr. {{teacher.firstName}} {{teacher.lastName}}, {{teacher.specialty}}
            </v-card-title>

            <v-card-text class='body-1'>
              M.S at {{teacher.ms}} <br> M.S.C at {{teacher.msc}}
            </v-card-text>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn outline color='blue'>
                More...
              </v-btn>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn outline color='green'>
                Appointments
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
```

I have tested this and there is no size below 300px (minimum for v-card) where the buttons don't look fine.
Made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/xon5/pen/MMVGGK) for you too.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I have tried option #3 but I still face the same problem upon resizing my browser.

Comment: Has it improved it at least? What width screen are you testing with?

Comment: No, not really. It's as if the v-button elements are fixed on the specific position. Haven't tested with a specific screen size, just resized the browser. If you replicate this, you can see for yourself.

Comment: Added the code I used to test this. I also added appropriate sizing to the `v-flex` so it changes properly with different window sizes. Your provided code had some errors there.

Comment: Thar worked. I guess the issue was in the attributes of v-flex. Thanks!